# Make "Log in" link into a modal box?

Tags: feature-request

I clear my browser cookies each day, and log into StackOverflow with my oAuth quite a lot. Something that would be simpler is if we had Login change from something where it's on it's own page into somehing where a click will pop-up a div as in the style of the global inbox.

It might look something like this (only, less ugly):

[image]

Benefits are a faster experience (at the very least, I personally notice the delay between going from a normal page to the log in page), eyes move less (the new page makes me look a bit more). Drawbacks are obviously having to do a bit of work, perhaps a larger page to load (granted, I doubt this would add anything so intensive it jeopardizes the normal customer experience).

The experience works great for me on Trello, which is where I got the idea:

[image]

[(Yes, this was also posted on meta.so, it was suggested I post here as well)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3743594#3743594)